# Windows Installation Setup won't Start

Tags: windows-7, windows

I just formatted and installed windows 7 in my asus laptop and error appears when installation is on going, because of this I decided to shut down my laptop and install again windows 7
but the setup won't continue. it appears in my screen "Setup is starting" with about 3 hours more.

I also tried to repair my computer but nothing appears in the screen.

What can I do??? Please Help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to continue the aborted setup or start anew? Boot from the DVD, start afresh, format again and install Win7. If you encounter errors, note them down carefully (take clear snapshots with a camera if possible) and add them to your question above.

Answer (score 0):

if you are ok with losing the data on the hard drive and have recovery media (USB/DVD), you can "clean" the drive and restart the reinstall process.  if you don't have recovery media, you'll need to either create it... or order from ASUS.

Comment: thanks for the mediate reply!but how can i create a recovery media?

Comment: you created it when you you got the computer right? you know, the nag screen that pops up and reminds you to burn some DVDs/CDs?  Most people ignore this.  (Some machines don't remind you FWIW, and you have to go dig for it).  Since you are able to boot into the recovery partition (the windows setup screen).  you likely can format the "c" partition.  But I am hesitant to explain how to do that because if you do the wrong partition, you can wipe the recovery partition out and end up with a completely blank hard drive.